# AspectJ and Maven

Tags: java, maven, aspectj

I try to get AspectJ working in an exisiting project (actually I don't know much about that project, because it seemed unimportant).

We decided to use the load time weaving to avoid using **ajc**

Because I'm new to AspectJ I created first an example project with some classes and a logging aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

    @Pointcut("call(public de.test.beans.IPerson+.*(..))")
    public void logExecutions(JoinPoint jp) {}

    @Before("logExecutions(jp)")
    public void beforeExecutions(JoinPoint jp) {
        BeforeExecutionLog log = new BeforeExecutionLog(jp);
        System.out.println(log);                
    }

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "logExecutions(jp)", returning = "ret")
    public void afterExecutions(JoinPoint jp, Object ret) {
        AfterExecutionLog log = new AfterExecutionLog(jp, ret);        
        System.out.println(log);        
    }    

}
```

It's working fine, everything is nice.

As next step I tried to use AspectJ and Maven together. I just changed the logging aspect a bit (just the package).

According to code from the book "AspectJ in Action" I modified our maven pom.xml

```
       <dependencies>
            ...
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
           <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
           <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.12.M1</version>
        </dependency>       
       </dependencies>
        <plugin>                                                 
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>            
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <executions>                                         
                <execution>                                      
                    <goals>                                      
                        <goal>compile</goal>                     
                    </goals>                                     
                    <configuration>                              
                        <source>1.5</source>                     
                        <target>1.5</target>                     
                    </configuration>                             
                </execution>                                     
            </executions>                                        
        </plugin>
```

But if try to call **mvn clean install** I get thousands of errors and the first one is:

```
[ERROR] Syntax error on token "call(public xxx.yyy.zzz.api.Service+.*(..))", "name pattern" expected
[ERROR] Method annotated with @Pointcut() for abstract pointcut must be abstract
```

There are also following errors:

```
[ERROR] The method xyz() of type zyx must override a superclass method
```

I guess these are all methods which are affected by my aspect.

Can anybody explain me, what is wrong?

Thank you in advance

**UPD:**

I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example seem incomplete and errors you showed doesn't match the code, but I don't see any issues compiling your aspect class using the following pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.5</source>
                            <target>1.5</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Privet Eugene. Actually, I just forgot to add these details. But aspectjrt and aspectjweaver are in pom.xml

Comment: What I noticed, the source and target versions in configuration affecting the behaviour

Comment: Your pointcut declaration is referring to de.test.beans.IPerson class and compilation warnings are about com.bmw.psdz.api.Service. So, either you provided wrong example, or your error is not related to the code you have shown.

Comment: You are right, there are an example project and an existing project. I try to understand, what this error says to me "Method annotated with @Pointcut() for abstract pointcut must be abstract"

Comment: You are right, Eugene. The code was different, the pointcut was different - @Pointcut("call(public xxx.yyy.zzz.api.Service+.*(..))"). After changing it to @Pointcut("call(public * xxx.yyy.zzz.api.Service+.*(..))") I could compile everything. Sometimes "истина где-то рядом - the truth is out there" :( And thank you

Comment: So, if you want to go with idioms, here is one for you: "Спасибо в карман не положишь". Give me some credit. :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it will be useful for someone.

```
[ERROR] The method xyz() of type zyx must override a superclass method
```

this error appears then you try to compile code with javac ver1.5 and have @Override annotation over the methods that just implemented in java class.

```
public interface A { void someMethod(); }
public class B implements A {
  @Override
  public void someMethod() {
    doSomething();
  }
}
```

i use this

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.6</source>
    <target>1.6</target>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Find [here in detail](http://aspectj.2085585.n4.nabble.com/AspectJ-and-Override-annotation-td2081801.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in a name pattern: return type is missing.
Try asterix for any type:

```
@Pointcut("call(public * de.test.beans.IPerson+.*(..))")
```